# spliting a column to two by a select query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like..

```
 +-----+-------------+--------+
 |  ID | EarningName |  Type  |
 +-----+-------------+--------+
 | 101 | ravi        |  R     |
 | 103 | sadham      |  D     |
 | 103 | sadham      |  D     |
 | 102 | rahul       |  D     |
 | 101 | rakhav      |  R     |
 | 101 | nithin      |  R     |
 | 103 | sumesh      |  D     | 
 | 101 | joil        |  R     |
 | 101 | manu        |  R     |
 | 102 | mubi        |  R     |
 | 103 | pradeep     |  D     |
 | 102 | sree        |  R     |
 | 102 | sajeev      |  R     |
 | 102 | ansu        |  R     |
 | 101 | prasad      |  D     |
 | 103 | milin       |  R     |
 | 103 | abhilash    |  R     |
 | 102 |    praveen  |  D     |
 | 103 | kiran       |  R     |
 +-----+-------------+--------+
```

> I want a postgresql select Query that produce following output
>   (join based on id and split based on type. The output must get like
>   the following structure).

```
+-----+-------------+--------------+
|  ID | EarningName |  DeductName  |
+-----+-------------+--------------+
| 101 | ravi        |   prasad     |
| 101 | rakhav      |   sumesh     |
| 101 | joil        |              |
| 101 | manu        |              |
| 102 | mubi        |   rahul      |
| 102 | sree        |   praveen    |
| 102 | sajeev      |              |
| 102 | ansu        |              | 
| 103 | milin       |   nithin     |
| 103 | abhilash    |   pradeep    |
| 103 | kiran       |   sadham     |
| 103 |             |   rajesh     |
+-----+-------------+--------------+

  I wrote some queries using LEFT JOIN ,But i didn't get like the above structure ..
```

Comment: `ID` for `sumesh` is `103` and why it should come after `101 | rakhav`?

Comment: The algorithm is ambiguous. 
Why `ravi` should be connected to `prasad` (and why not e.g. `joil` with `prasad`?). 
You need to define an additional order of names within the id to make the algorithm unambiguos.

Answer (score 2):

This is trickier than I first thought.  You are trying to get two lists in two columns, and they appear to be unordered.  The solution is still conditional aggregation, but now you need a column to enumerate the values as well as the id:

```
select id,
       max(case when Type = 'R' then name end) as EarningName,
       max(case when Type = 'D' then name end) as DeductName
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, type order by id) as seqnum
      from atablelike t
     ) t
group by id, seqnum;
```